# How can I get the calendar id of members belonging to google groups by google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I referenced https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar#listing_events

```
var TEAM_CALENDAR_ID = 'team_calender_id'
var GROUP_EMAIL = 'group_email@group.com';

var KEYWORDS = ['vacation']
var MONTHS_IN_ADVANCE = 3;
.
.

function listNext10Events() {
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var now = new Date();
  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
    timeMin: now.toISOString(),
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
    maxResults: 10
  });
```

I want to assign the calendarId of another group member to the calendarId variable, and put that calendarId as the 'Calendar.Events.list' argument to get a list of other people's events. How can I get other people's valid calendarId ?

I put a valid calendarId , but response is assigned a different value than my expectation.

Comment: `but response is assigned a different value than my expectation.` what is the response and what is your expectation?

Comment: Hang on - you can't list someone else's calendar events if it's not shared with you unless you're authenticated as them. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo thx. If it works, events.items is not empty. But there is nothing in events.items. It works very well at https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list :(

Comment: I resolved a problem. It was caused by date format. Thx @RafaGuillermo help:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list the events for another calendar you would simply supply the calendar id of the calendar you want to access.

```
function listNext10Events() {
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var now = new Date();
  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
    timeMin: now.toISOString(),
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
    maxResults: 10
  });
```

In the method above you are using primary as the calendar id you wish to access this is the primary calendar of the currently authenticated user, you could also use their email address to get this primary calendar.

So if you wanted to access my primary calendar you could simply change it to my email address. However for that to work i would have had to grant you permissions to access my calendar.

So to access another calendar by another user you simply need to ask them what the calendar id is and ask them to grant you permission to access it.  Alternatively you could let them authorize your application then they could access it themselves.